# Unwanted virtual keyboard in Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, virtual-keyboard

I have developed a Blackberry app for the 4.5 os series.
It works fine on all device except on the storm 1 (storm2 untested).

The problem (on the storm) is that the main screen of my application (and all other screens in fact) is shown with the virtual keybord. But there is no text field displayed on the screen that would justify the VK to show up.
I have bitmap fields and button fields only on that screen.
The use of a single program for all devices (4.5 and up) is seriously preferred.

What is causing the VK to show up and what can I do to prevent it (in JDE 4.5)?

Answer (score 3):

You could compile your application for OS 5.0 or 4.7(depending on the OS on the device) on the storm to make sure the app will not run in compatibility mode.

Or you can change how your app is setup in the JAD.

Here is a [KB article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800719/What_Is_-_Compatibility_mode_on_touch_screen_BlackBerry_smartphones.html?nodeid=1487544&vernum=0) from RIM

```
RIM-TouchCompatibilityMode: false
RIM-TouchCompatibilityMode-UserChangeable: false
```

You can also [disable compatibility mode] within the device after the app is installed[2](http://www.rimarkable.com/blackberry-storm-usability-tip-disable-compatibility-mode).

1. Navigate to the Applications list by
   clicking Options -> Advanced Options
   -> Applications.
2. Locate and select the third-party
   application.
3. Display the menu and click Disable
   Compatibility Mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(VirtualKeyboard.isSupported())
    getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE); //Force to close the virtual Keyboard.
```

you will compile in 4.7 and use preprocesor directives to detect if Virtual Keyboard is supported, then force to close..

```
        //#ifdef BlackBerrySDK4.7.0
                if(VirtualKeyboard.isSupported())
        getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE);
        //#endif
```